# How can I send request to Telegram API, when my Hosting blocks it?

Tags: php, api, proxy, telegram, telegram-bot

My Hosting blocks any requests to Telegram API.

I need to avoid this protection and make requests sent.

In other words - Let server A go through server B to make request to Telegram API. Maybe something like that:

```
file_get_contents('https://myproxyserver.com/proxy.php?target=https://api.telegram.org/bot'. $token .'/sendMessage?chat_id='. $chat_id .'&text=' . urlencode($msg));
```

Is there any solution to realize this stuff with php?

I would appreciate any kind of help or links that may help me!

Comment: Are they blocking specific services API's? That seems very odd. Anyway, you could just create an API on some other server that handles the communication to Telegram's API.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thank you for your response! If you know Russia blocks all traffics to Telegram and his services, but unfortunatelly I can't move to another hosting for some reasons.  Could you advice resources where I can get info about how to create that API server which will handle the communication to Telegram's API?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. But if you just google something like "create rest api php" you will most likely find hundreds, if not thousands, of tutorials about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to figure it out on my own. Will try  to create REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server blocks the outgoing requests to Telegram web servers, you have a couple of options:

- If you have a VPS or a dedicated server, you can install TOR or some VPNs and make your requests through that VPN (anything which make you able to make anonymous communication). For doing this, you need the ability to install those software on your server
- You can use HTTP proxy servers and make your request indirectly (you may find some free ones on Internet).
- If you have or you can have another host outside of Russia (and also Iran where I live!), and put an script there and use that script as a proxy. For this, you may also use `jenssegers/proxy` package which provides a clean way for this.

For these options, instead of file_get_contents, use *CURL* or *Guzzle* which have more capabilities and flexibility including the use of HTTP/SOCKS proxy.